# C++ MFC Displaying Bitmap Image File

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, mfc

I have the following code:

```
BOOL CDemoDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    ShowWindow(1);

    m_pMCE = new ExternalInterface();
    m_pMCE ->SetCallbackWindow(int(m_hWnd)); // m_hWnd is a Windows handle

    m_pMCE->LoadPreset(7);
    m_pImgDisp = new ImgDisplay;
    m_pImgDisp->Setup(m_pMCE ->ImgWidth(),m_pMCE ->ImgHeight(), m_eView.GetDC());

    // ADDED CODE BELOW THIS FOR DISPLAYING BMP IMAGE
    HDC m_memDC;
    m_memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(m_eView.GetDC()->m_hDC);
    HBITMAP bitmap;
    bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "C:\\Me\\Demo\\x64\\Debug\\images\\demo0.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
    SelectObject(m_memDC, bitmap);
    BitBlt(m_eView.GetDC()->m_hDC, 0, 0, m_pMCE->ImgWidth(), m_pMCE->ImgHeight(), m_memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    SetTimer(GUI_LIFE_TIMER, 1000, NULL);
    Py_Initialize(); // initialize python interpreter
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

I'm trying to display my .bmp file in the window based on the handle, but for some reason, it's not showing up at all. I think, when I run the program, I see the bmp image show up but only for a brief millisecond.

Is there anything I'm missing in my code?

I'm also new to Windows programming, so not sure if there are other ways which I can test my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What type of control is your `m_eView` member? You may need to make it custom-drawn and do the `BitBlt` in the `OnDrawItem` override for that control.

Comment: Windows does not have a "paint and forget" model. You need to respond to the `WM_PAINT` message and paint your image whenever Windows asks you to.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thanks for your response! m_eView is from another class that I'm dealing with. It's an ExternalInterface class that I didn't create. I don't believe there's an OnDrawItem method here as well. How would I make it custom-drawn?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for your response! So you mean I can't just display some image right off the bat and leave it there? That's not possible in Windows? Basically I just want to open the window and display the bitmap image there. How can I respond to the message in that case?

Comment: As @JonathanPotter suggested, you can override your dialog's `OnPaint` function and do the drawing in there (much the same way as you've done in your `OnInitDialog` function).

Comment: Place a [CStatic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstatic-class) control on your dialog and call [SetBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstatic-class#setbitmap). Make sure you understand, that you will not learn Windows programming with MFC. MFC is meant for developers that know Windows programming already.